# how to show in a table the last 3 elements vue js c#

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, vuejs2

I am programming in vue js and c#. I am having an error.
I need it to bring me the last 3 tasks, the budgets brings me BudgetTask and there in presupuestos[0].presupuestoTareas.descripcion, it brings me the text that I want to show as seen in the second image, because when it brings me the data it brings me an array of 9 objects and I only want 3 of those 9 to be displayed. I was thinking about doing a for, map, but I can't hit the right point, in the second image it brings me those 3, but I'm not given any other idea.
In case you didn't understand it, I'll explain again briefly, in the presupuesto controller, the result receives a presupuesto list, including this presupuesto.presupuestoTarea, that presupuestoTarea loads me with the 9 tasks, and what I want is for it to load only the last 3, so at the time of rendering they look good in my html. Thank you very much, I hope my information has served you.

PRESUPUESTO CONTROLLER

```
/// <summary>
    /// Listado completo de objetos.
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("getListSupervisar")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Presupuesto>>> GetListSupervisar([FromQuery] int? tipoPresupuesto, [FromQuery] int? clienteId, [FromQuery] int? procesoId, [FromQuery] int? tareaId)
    {
        string[] _include = { nameof(Presupuesto.Usuario),
            nameof(Presupuesto.Cliente),
            nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.PresupuestoDetalleProceso),
            nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.ArticuloBp),
            nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle) + "." + nameof(PresupuestoDetalle.ArticuloCamara),
            nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoTarea),
            nameof(Presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario)
        };

        var result = await _presupuestoServices.GetListAsync(a => a.Id > 0
                                                            && a.TipoPresupuesto!=null
                                                            && ((tipoPresupuesto == null && a.TipoPresupuesto != (int)Enumeraciones.PresupuestoTipo.Presupuesto) || a.TipoPresupuesto == tipoPresupuesto)
                                                            && (tareaId == null || a.PresupuestoTarea.Where(b => b.TareaId == tareaId).Count() > 0)
                                                            && (procesoId == null || a.PresupuestoDetalle.Where(b => b.PresupuestoDetalleProceso.Where(c => c.ProcesoId == procesoId && c.Cantidad < b.Cantidad).Count() > 0).Count() > 0)
                                                            && (clienteId == null || a.ClienteId == clienteId)
                                                            && a.PresupuestoDetalle.Count > 0
                                                            , _include);

        var list = new List<Presupuesto>();

        foreach (var presupuesto in result.ToList())
        {
            //presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle = presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Where(a => a.EsPrimerCristal == true).ToList();
            presupuesto.Procesos = ArmarProcesosFaltantes(presupuesto);
            presupuesto.PresupuestoComentarioString = presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario.Count>0 ? presupuesto.PresupuestoComentario.LastOrDefault().Comentario : "";

            if (presupuesto.ImporteEnvio>0) 
            {
                presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Envio", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = 1, Alto = 1,Presupuesto = presupuesto });
            }
            if (presupuesto.ImporteDescuento > 0) 
            {
                var descuentoPorcen = (presupuesto.DescuentoExtraPorcen + presupuesto.Cliente.Descuento)/100;
                presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Descuento", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = descuentoPorcen, Alto = descuentoPorcen, Presupuesto = presupuesto });
            }
            if (presupuesto.ImporteColocacion > 0)
            {
                presupuesto.PresupuestoDetalle.Add(new PresupuestoDetalle() { Descripcion = "Colocacion", Cantidad = 1, Ancho = 1, Alto = 1, Presupuesto = presupuesto });
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

PRESUPUESTO ENTITIES

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Taller.Model.Entities
{
[Table("Presupuesto")]
public class Presupuesto
{
    public Presupuesto()
    {
        PresupuestoHija = new HashSet<Presupuesto>();
        PresupuestoDetalle = new HashSet<PresupuestoDetalle>();            
        PresupuestoTarea = new HashSet<PresupuestoTarea>();
        PresupuestoComentario = new HashSet<PresupuestoComentario>();
        Archivo = new HashSet<Archivo>();

    }
    #region Propiedades
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Numero { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaAlta {get; set;}

    public DateTime? FechaModificacion { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FechaEntrega { get; set; }

    public int? DiasEntrega { get; set; }

    public int? Estado { get; set; }

    public string DireccionObra { get; set; }    

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? DescuentoExtraPorcen { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteIva { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteSubTotal { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteDescuento { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteNetoGravado { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteNetoNoGravado { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteExento { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteImpuestos { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteEnvio { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteColocacion { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal? ImporteTotal { get; set; }

    public int? TipoDespacho { get; set; }

    public int? TipoPresupuesto { get; set; }
    public int? Plano { get; set; }
    public int? PresupuestoMadreId { get; set; }

    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }

    public int? FormaPagoId { get; set; }



    #endregion
    #region Calculados
    [NotMapped]
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string PresupuestoComentarioString { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string EstadoString { 
        get 
        {
            var result = "";
            switch (Estado)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = "Pendiente";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = "En_Proceso";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = "Terminada";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string TipoDespachoString
    {
        get
        {
            var result = "";
            switch (Estado)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = "Mostrador";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = "Envio";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = "Colocacion";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = "Carpinteria";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string TipoPresupuestoString
    {
        get
        {
            var result = "";
            switch (TipoPresupuesto)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = "Presupuesto";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = "O_T";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = "O_T_Madre";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = "O_T_Hija";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    result = "Reposicion";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    result = "Especial";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public string Tareas
    {
        get
        {
            var result = "";
            foreach (var item in PresupuestoTarea.OrderBy(a=>a.FechaAlta))
            {
                result = item.Descripcion + " " + result;

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> Procesos { get; set; }

    #endregion
    #region Relaciones
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public FormaPago FormaPago { get; set; }

    public Presupuesto PresupuestoMadre { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Presupuesto> PresupuestoHija { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PresupuestoDetalle> PresupuestoDetalle { get; set; } 

    public ICollection<PresupuestoTarea> PresupuestoTarea { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PresupuestoComentario> PresupuestoComentario { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Archivo> Archivo { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
}
```

ESTE ES MI TEMPLATE

```
<v-card-title class="text-h3 dark lighten-2">
    Documentos
  </v-card-title>

  <v-simple-table fixed-header height="300px">
    <template v-slot:default>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-left">Tipo</th>
          <th class="text-left">Numero trabajo</th>
          <th class="text-left">Cliente</th>
          <th class="text-left">Entrega</th>
          <th class="text-left">Comentario</th>
          <th class="text-left">Tareas</th>
          <th class="text-right">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="item in presupuestos"
          :key="item.id"
          :style="item.id === presupuestoSeleccionado.id && TheStyle"
        >
          <td>{{ item.tipoPresupuestoString }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.numero }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.cliente.nombre }}</td>
          <td>{{ formatDate(item.fechaEntrega) }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.presupuestoComentarioString }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.tareas }}</td>
          <td class="text-left">
            <v-icon
              title="Seleccionar OT"
              @click="selectedPresupuesto(item)"
              >mdi-tab-search</v-icon
            >
            <v-icon title="Nueva Tarea" @click="abrirPopupNuevaTarea(item)"
              >mdi-hospital</v-icon
            >
            <v-icon
              title="Listado de Tareas"
              @click="abrirPopupListadoTarea(item)"
            >
              mdi-archive-edit-outline
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
              title="Agregar comentario"
              @click="popUpComentario(item)"
              >mdi-message</v-icon
            >
            <v-icon
              title="Control Madres e Hijas"
              class="text-center"
              v-show="item.tipoPresupuesto === 3"
              @click="download(item)"
              >mdi-download</v-icon
            >
            <v-icon
              title="Terminar Orden"
              class="text-center"
              @click="changeEstado(item, 3)"
              >mdi-checkbox-multiple-marked</v-icon
            >
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-simple-table>
```

ESTE ES EL DATA

```
 data() {
return {
  selected: false,
  formComentario: {
    comentario: "",
  },
  cliente: null,
  clientes: [],
  presupuestos: [],
  tipoPresupuesto: null,
  selectedRow: null,
  tipoPresupuestos: [
    { value: 2, text: "O_T" },
    { value: 3, text: "O_T_Madre" },
    { value: 4, text: "O_T_Hija" },
    { value: 5, text: "Reposicion" },
    { value: 6, text: "Especial" },
  ],
  presupuestoSeleccionado: {
    presupuestoDetalle: [],
    procesos: [],
  },
  proceso: null,
  procesos: [],
  tarea: null,
  tareaFiltro: null,
  tareas: [],
  empleado: null,
  presupuestoTareaDescripcion: null,
  showpresupuestoTareaDescripcion: false,
  empleados: [],
  tareaEmpleados: [],
  presupuestoDetalleProcesos: [],
  popupNuevaTarea: false,
  popupListadoTareas: false,
  popUpPresupuestoDetalleProceso: false,
  popUpNuevoComentario: false,
  presupuestoTareas: [],
  presupuestoComentarios: [],
  labelTituloDetalleProceso: "",
  labelCantidadDetalleProceso: "",
  TheStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "",
  },
};
},
```

METODO

```
methods: {


getList() {
  const tipoPresupuesto =
    this.tipoPresupuesto != null ? this.tipoPresupuesto : "";
  const clienteId = this.cliente != null ? this.cliente.id : "";
  const procesoId = this.proceso != null ? this.proceso : "";
  const tareaId = this.tareaFiltro != null ? this.tareaFiltro : "";

  Swal.fire({
    title: "Espere unos momentos ...",
    showConfirmButton: false,
  });
  this.presupuestoServices
    .getListSupervisar(tipoPresupuesto, clienteId, procesoId, tareaId)
    .then((data) => {
      Swal.close();
      console.log("soy data antes", data);
      this.presupuestos = data;
      console.log('capaz puede andar',this.presupuestos[0].presupuestoTarea.slice(-3))
      this.$data.TheStyle.backgroundColor = "#c3bbbb"; //Para seleccionar los row de algun color
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      Swal.close();
      this.showError(error.response.data);
    });
},
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the c# part is relevant for your question, as I understand it.

If you only want to render the last three items of an array, you could do that in different ways, but I think the cleanest way is to use [a computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example) and use that as the input for the v-for loop.

Below your data section in your Vue component add the computed property like:

```
computed: {
    lastThree() {
      return this.presupuestos.slice(this.presupuestos.length - 3)
    }
 }
```

Now you can use the computed property in your template, like:

```
<tr v-for="item in lastThree" :key="item.id" ...>
```

EDIT: [here is a simple working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kktugzAQhq8y8iaJFEBt+qS0Uk/QTXd1FxQmwSkYyza0EeLutR0CKLG6gZlv4J9nR16FCNsGSUwSlUkm9AvlAPgraqkhx23alBo6ywDyVKfL1ckDkKgbyScfgGmsVAwfEwFYWAhXi/UlvPbBjQ/e+OCtD9754L0PPvjg4xx+nsz+aPRrOBpZXYlGYw7x1H2ZKv1eSMT5iMYh6YKp0I0nVCXLcDkDJfKdLiCAzerpPKN9mUcSjdsxjvlLlKlGt6s3Xh6MPLoCjGEqGPZgo0nOWmiDbS2fKXEdMj6VSgnE33gYQpQ4QYCucwrQu/RJZDRMJInGvGRNWGVPJKhSEe5Vzc0BuaaNkgsoSsbZUGIuzPqUFFoLFUeR2mb27PYqrOUuMlYoG65ZhSGqKviS9Y9CaYQpGdbhNCIDW5SBRJ6jRPmf5tmnF7rDYHvS/wGTC+cg)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But that would show me the last 3 budgets, I need to show the last 3 of, presupuesto.presupuestoTarea... Besides, I already have the v-for... please give me more information, because it is not very well understood. Let's see if I explain myself, presupuesto brings 2 elements... if I enter the first presupuesto[0] it shows me all the props among them presupuestoTarea is an array of 9 objects, from that presupuestoTarea I need to show the last 3. And set it to the presupuesto I imagine . So when I show the item.tareas in the table it shows me only 3 tasks.

Comment: Okay, well then you put `return this.presupuesto[0].presupuestoTarea.slice(this.presupuestos.length - 3)` in the computed property. And you can use `lastTree` as a variable, with only the last three items of the presupuestoTarea array.

Comment: Just made a simple example for you here. Hope this helps. https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNptkktugzAQhq8y8iaJFEBt+qS0Uk/QTXd1FxQmwSkYyx7SRoi713YSiBpvYOYb+Z9nz16VincdspRlptBC0QuXAPirWk1Q4jrvaoLeMYAyp3y+OHkAGqnTcvIBBGFjUviYCMDMQbiaLS/hdQiuQvAmBG9D8C4E70PwIQQfz+HnyRwOxrCEg1G0jeoIS0in7uvc0HulEc9HNA6JKmFiP57Y1KLA+RmoUW6ogghWi6f/Gd3PfrJk3I517CtV54R+V2+y3lt59AVYw1Zw3IOLZqXYwS5at/qZM9+hkFOpnEH6jftjiDMvCND3XgEGnz5LrIaNZMmYly2ZaNyJRE2u4q1ppT0g37RV8gHD2TgbzuyFOZ+zikiZNEnMunBntzVxqzeJtWLdSRINxmia6Eu3Pwa1FebsOICBDX+VXcft